# ElasticSearch Date Range Aggregation over different fields

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I want to be able to fetch documents over a certain date range as provided by the user and the display the document to be viewed. The query that i have currently constructed looks like this :
**query**

```
    {
        "aggs": {
            "range": {
                "date_range": {
                    "field": "metadata.o2r.temporal.begin",
                    "ranges": [
                        { "from": "2017-03-30T12:35:41.142Z",  "to": "2017-08-02T22:00:00.000Z", "key": "quarter_01" }
                    ],
                    "keyed": true
                }
            }
        }
    }

'
```

The temporal part of the json documents that i am trying to fetch are like the following:

**JSON**

```
"temporal": {
"begin": "2017-08-01T22:00:00.000Z",
"end": "2017-03-30T12:35:41.142Z"
},
```

Currently i can either query "begin" or "end" but i want to be able to modify the query in such a way that **begin** becomes a value for "from" and **end** becomes a values for "to". The catch is here that i do not want my original JSON to be modified.

**Updated Query**

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9201/test/_search?size=0&pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
> {
> "query": {
>     "bool": {
>         "must": [
>            {
>                "range": {
>                   "metadata.o2r.temporal.begin": {
>                      "from": "2016-01-01T12:35:41.142Z"
>                   }
>                }
>            } , 
>            {
>                "range": {
>                   "metadata.o2r.temporal.end": {
>                      "to": "2016-12-30T22:00:00.000Z"
>                    }
>                 } 
>             }
>           ]
>       }
>   }
> }
> '
```

**Response**

```
{
  "took" : 1678,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using aggregation ? Do u need aggregated data

Comment: @Richa well i want to show all the documents that fall within a certain date range and for that purpose in my humble opinion aggregation is better than date range query?

Comment: Well Aggregation will just fetch you the count unless you use sub aggregations.   Aren't u interseted in documents

Comment: @Richa i am but first i want to modify the query in a way as mentioned in the question

Comment: have answered it . See if it fits your requirement.

Comment: @Richa thanks! that solved the problem to a great extent. However i am unable to visualize the response that the query gets as only hits are shown in response? How can i be able to display the fetched json?

Comment: Did not get You .. `i am unable to visualize the response that the query gets as only hits are shown in response`. what else do you expect?

Comment: @Richa i am only seeing the total number of hits while actually i want to see the complete JSON as a response (a part of which i have shown in the question). i hope i am making my point clear..:)

Comment: You mean you are getting only count.In hits we always get complete source until `_source` is defined. That's strange you are getting only number

Comment: Can you please post the response you are getting

Comment: @Richa just added it to the post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144199/discussion-between-rehan-and-richa).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you

```
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
           {
               "range": {
                  "metadata.o2r.temporal.begin": {
                     "from": "2017-03-30T12:35:41.142Z"
                  }
               }
           } , 
           {
               "range": {
                  "metadata.o2r.temporal.end": {
                     "to": "2017-08-02T22:00:00.000Z"
                   }
                } 
            }
          ]
      }
  }
}
```